# Прелоадер при открытии модального

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

как сделать прелоадер при загрузке данных в блок #new_window #select_complect?

модальное:

```
<div id="new_window" class="hidden">
    <div class="head">
        <p></p>
        <span class="close_window"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
        <div class="pic_popup"></div>
        <div id="select_complect" >

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

 function action_but(code, ttl){
        $("#new_window .head p").html(ttl);
        $.post("assets/get.php", { act:"list", сid:code})
        .done(function(data) {
            $("#new_window #select_complect").html(data);
        });
    }
```

файл get.php

```
if ($action == "list"){
    if (empty($_POST['сid'])) {exit();}
    $code = $_POST['сid'];
    $sql = "SELECT mp.`id` as pid,ms.`pagetitle` as pagetitle, mp.`thumb` as thumb FROM `modx_site_content` as ms
            LEFT JOIN `modx_ms2_products` mp on mp.`id`=ms.`id`
            where ms.`parent`='.$code.'";
        $statement = $modx->query($sql);
        $parent = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach ($parent as $res) {
                  $output .= '<div class="clearfix element">
                      <div class="pic">
                              <span>
                                <img src="'.$res['thumb'].'">
                              </span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="info wpic">
                            <div class="name">'.$res['pagetitle'].'</div>
                        </div>
                        <button data-id="'.$res['pid'].'" data-parent="'.$code.'" class="button choise">Выбрать</button>
                    </div>';
            }
    echo $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function action_but(code, ttl){
        $("#new_window .head p").html(ttl);
        $("#new_window #select_complect").html('Пошла загрузка');
        $.post("assets/get.php", { act:"list", сid:code})
        .done(function(data) {
            $("#new_window #select_complect").html(data);
        });
    }
```

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы появлялся прелоадер, а потом форма? а то сейчас появляется форма и через пол секунду данные подгружаются туда

Comment: добавьте  к вопросу пример верстки

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: а что Вы называете "формой" ? (содержание блока с классом "с")

Comment: да (11 символов нужно...)